# Gallery slider thumbnail not showing all images only 4 images

Tags: fotorama-slider

I'm having some problems this slider, all the products that have more than 4 images the others images are not loading and don't appear any error, but when we open the full image view the images are loaded and it appears in the slide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information? Any errors in your browser's developer console? Any 3rd party modules extending the gallery? Hard to guess the problem with the current information.

Comment: @Hoargarth any errors appear on console the only thing I notice is the thumbnails which the images are loaded the div tag applied these classes
<div class="fotorama__thumb fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img"><img src="http://p\c\3\//r/e/r-c-c-p-b-v.jpg" 
 class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false">
    </div>
and the other images the div tag have only this class <div class="fotorama__thumb">
    </div>

Comment: There must be some issues with lazyload, seems like it isnt working with scroll action, have you got anything by that regard? Seems like https://fotorama.io/docs/4/lazy-load/ the thumb is used to lazyload the Thumb images